# AWT-EventQueue-0 while render TIFF files

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to develop a image viewer in java, my code works good for almost all the formtas, but at the moment to render the images, I'm using the next code:

```
private ImageIcon scaleImage(int indice, int w, int h, boolean thumbnail) {        
        ImageIcon image = null;
        ImageIO.setUseCache(false);

        if(fileRefernces.get(indice).toLowerCase().endsWith("tif") || fileRefernces.get(indice).toLowerCase().endsWith("tiff")  ) {
            File initialImage = new File(fileRefernces.get(indice));        
            try {
                BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(initialImage);
                image = new ImageIcon(bImage); 
                bImage.flush();
                bImage = null;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(ImageRender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 
            initialImage = null;
        } else {
            image = new ImageIcon(fileRefernces.get(indice)); 
        }

        int nw = image.getIconWidth();
        int nh = image.getIconHeight();

        if(nw > w) {
          nw = w;
          nh = (nw * image.getIconHeight()) / image.getIconWidth();
        }

        if(nh > h) {
          nh = h;
          nw = (image.getIconWidth() * nh) / image.getIconHeight();
        }

        System.gc();

        return (thumbnail) 
                ? new ImageIcon(image.getImage().getScaledInstance(nw, nh, Image.SCALE_FAST )) 
                : new ImageIcon(image.getImage().getScaledInstance(nw, nh, Image.DEFAULT));
    }
```

But, I get the next error while is running.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.scaleImage(ImageRender.java:815)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.lambda$CargarDocumento$2(ImageRender.java:700)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.scaleImage(ImageRender.java:815)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.CompletarMiniaturas(ImageRender.java:752)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.lambda$CargarDocumento$3(ImageRender.java:716)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.scaleImage(ImageRender.java:815)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.lambda$CargarDocumento$2(ImageRender.java:700)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.scaleImage(ImageRender.java:815)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.CompletarMiniaturas(ImageRender.java:752)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.lambda$CargarDocumento$3(ImageRender.java:716)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.scaleImage(ImageRender.java:815)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.CompletarMiniaturas(ImageRender.java:752)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.lambda$CargarDocumento$3(ImageRender.java:716)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.scaleImage(ImageRender.java:815)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.lambda$CargarDocumento$2(ImageRender.java:700)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.scaleImage(ImageRender.java:815)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.lambda$CargarDocumento$2(ImageRender.java:700)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.scaleImage(ImageRender.java:815)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.CompletarMiniaturas(ImageRender.java:752)
        at com.bog.company.render.ImageRender.lambda$CargarDocumento$3(ImageRender.java:716)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But, this happens with the tif images. Someone has an idea about how to solve it?

Comment: I see you have an empty catch block, can you check if the code ends up in that block, as an ioexception in that block would cause an NPE later on

Comment: What java version are you using? 8? 9? 10? 11? 12? Something else?

Comment: `But, this happens with the tif images` - is Java able to read a .tif image? Did you check if the image is null?

Comment: @camickr I can read the images in some machinnes, but in other ones, I Can't

Comment: @Abra jdk1.8.0_201

Comment: Then I would guess the image isn't found. Again, what message to you get in the catch block. And why would you flush() the BufferedImage after reading it? What is different about the machines that work and those that don't? We can't answer those questions.

Comment: @camickr I dont have any clue about it. All are using jdk for 32 bits and the same jre version. And in one machinne works. What else I should check?

Comment: *"What else I should check?"* the message in the `catch` block. Where is your image located? Is it on the computer? On the JAR?

Comment: [getReaderFormatNames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getReaderFormatNames--) returns an array of supported format names. Check whether "tif" format is supported.